# How does one Android NDK library without a Android Project

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

I would like to be able to build a shared library in using the android ndk-build script, but for some reason I get a bunch of errors:

```
# I have Application.mk and Android.mk in the current folder
ndk-build -C . 
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
```

Is there a way to build the Android shared library with only the source and header files?$$\int$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can write

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```

But it's much easier to create `./jni` directory and put both **Application.mk** and **Android.mk** there.